# How to install drivers for all users in windows 11

Tags: drivers, user-accounts, windows-11

I have two accounts in my Windows 11 machine: "Administrator" and "John".

I installed the driver for my digital graphic tablet in Administrator account, and everything works perfectly.

However, the driver must be installed and re-installed (using "Administrator" privileges) every single time "John" logs in.

Is there any way to install the driver so that "John" wouldn't need to install it every single time?

Comment: What model is the graphic tablet and which driver was installed?

Comment: It is Gaomon S620 and here is the driver's download page: https://www.gaomon.net/plus/list.php?cateId=12&type=0&system=0&Keyword=&tid=9#pcb

Comment: Did you follow [this procedure](https://www.gaomon.net/question/uninstall_driver.html) when installing the new driver?

Comment: No, I didn't follow that, I just followed what was recommended in the user manual, thank you for the link! Have to get off my computer for now, I will give this a go tomorrow and report how it went.

Comment: As a (amongst other titles) windows device driver developer, I can tell you that what is currently called a driver is complicated.  The definition has been changed over time.  Originally, drivers were something that ran inside of the kernel ONLY and is all users ONLY.  MS has redefined what a driver IS.  IMHO, those aren't drivers (and I have written a few).  Things like tablet, scanner, printer, and the like can have "User mode" drivers which may or not be system wide.  I would say that anything that requires re-installed, ***is not a driver*** IMHO,

Comment: @harrymc: I tried to install it based on the procedure you mentioned in your comment, but it didn't work.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I think this is exactly the issue here, so I believe the "driver" that I downloaded is NOT actually a driver but more of an application. As per [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-allow-all-program-access-to-all-users-on/0d662992-8e91-4b21-ab0a-efa6cc58ce39), for this third part APPLICATION (imo), the option "install for everyone" is simply not available. I have however contacted the manufacturer and asked for their comments. I will keep you updated if I hear something from them.

Comment: Why don't you install the driver as John and when prompted for elevated permissions provide the Administrator password.  You shouldn't use the built-in Administrator account, that account shouldn't even be enabled, it should only exist in the event you need it. You should create your own Administrator account.

Comment: The problem was solved and I have to say that the Gaomon support was really supportive and helpful, so you need to right click the GAOMON driver icon on the desktop, then click "open the location of the file", then go one level up in directory to reach Roaming, then apply these changes to two directories: GAOMON and GAOMONTablet: right click on the directory, then Properties, then Security, then Edit, then Add "everyone", and give "everyone" full Control in permissions, and then Apply.

Answer (score 2):

True drivers are machine oriented and always for All Users.

Applications (like a graphic tablet) may be By User, or have an option for All Users.

Check the Installation for All Users and do it that way.

If no option for All Users, then you must install for each user.

It may help to log in as USER and then do the tablet install with Admin Credentials.

If all fails, double check the manual for install instructions and (or) register a case with the tablet manufacturer.

Comment: It is advertised as a driver (https://www.gaomon.net/plus/list.php?cateId=12&type=0&system=0&Keyword=&tid=9#pcb), but in reality it could be an application, idk. There was no option to install for All Users. It can be installed for each user, but the problem is that the installation is "forgotten" after logout, so for "John", the driver should be installed every single time he logs in. For the "Administartor", it suffices to be installed only once.

Comment: It may help to log in as USER and then install the tablet as Administrator.  That will normally work and I added that to my answer

Comment: This is what I do all the time! With "John" logged in, there is no way to install the driver with normal privileges, so every single time it has to be installed as Administrator. As you mentioned, I probably have to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: As I noted log a case with manufacturer support.  The way outlined is how to install user software